# Set element's values to Bootstrap dropdown

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have this jQuery code to auto-select an element for two Bootstrap dropdown.

```
function selectOption(){
    $(".dropdown-menu li a").click(function(){
        $(this).parents(".dropdown").find('.btn').html($(this).text() + ' <span class="caret"></span>');
        $(this).parents(".dropdown").find('.btn').val($(this).data('value'));
    });
}

$('#floor').click(function(e) {
    var name = e.target.name;
    $('#room').children().remove().end();
    $.post('GetRoom', {floor:name}, function(data){
        var pre = 0;
        for(i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
            if(data[i] === ">"){
                var room = data.substring(pre, i);
                $('#room').append('<li><a href="#" name="' + room + '">' + room + '</a></li>');
                pre = i + 1;
            }
        }
    });
    e.preventDefault();
});

$('#room').click(function(e){
    var name = e.target.name;
    $.post('GetPeople', {flag:1, room:name}, function(data){
        $('#sector_2').children().remove().end();
        if(data.length > 0){
            $('#sector_2').append('<table class="table table-bordered" id="table_People"></table>');
            $('#table_People').append('<thead><tr><th>Mã sinh viên</th><th>Mã thẻ</th><th>Tên sinh viên</th><th>Ngày sinh</th><th>Ngành học</th><th>Ngày vào</th><th>Ngày hết hạn</th><th>Tên phòng</th></tr></thead><tbody></tbody>');
            $('#table_People').find('tbody').append(data);
        }
    });
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

I execute it by onload event in body tag. And next is my html code:

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" style="width:270px; text-align:center">Chọn lầu
        <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="width:270px; text-align:center" id="floor">
        <li><a href="#" name="1">Lầu 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" name="2">Lầu 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" name="3">Lầu 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" name="4">Lầu 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" name="5">Lầu 5</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" name="6">Lầu 6</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" name="7">Lầu 7</a></li>
    </ul>       
</div>
<label> </label>
<div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" style="width:270px; text-align:center">Chọn phòng
        <span class="caret"></span>
            </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="width:270px; text-align:center" id="room">

    </ul>
```

The first dropdown with `id="floor"`, I can auto-set the value when I select an element of dropdown list. But the second one with `id="room"`, I can select an element of dropdown list but I can't auto-set the value. Can anybody help?

Comment: You might want to put your question towards the top, rather than at the end. That way people will know what you're trying to do before reading your code.

Comment: What do you mean by auto-setting the value ? I tried it [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MaWoRM) and even if it does not load the data, the label does not change at all, `selectOption` is not called anywhere

Comment: He says that it is executed on the `onload` defined in the body tag.